# Creating a new hyperlink field in FME

Tags: esri-geodatabase, fme-form

I have a table similar to the following attached to geometry destined for inclusion in an esri geodatabase:

[image]

What I am trying to do in FME, is create a new field containing a hyperlink to reference the file name and location of the reference number at a fixed networked location. For example:
[image]

Is this possible in FME and if so, what would be the best way to go about it? There are occasions where multiple concatenated reference fields exist, so I wonder if it's possible to also concatenate the hyperlinks or if they would be required to be split into separate fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly build URLs in FME. I would use the [**AttributeCreator**](https://docs.safe.com/fme/2017.1/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/attributecreator.htm) or [**AttributeManager**](https://docs.safe.com/fme/2017.1/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/attributemanager.htm) transformers. Within the transformer, you can build the hyperlink in the **[text editor](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Workbench/!Transformer_Parameters/text_editor.htm)**.

In order to enable these hyperlinks in ArcGIS, you will need to enable them in the Layer, not the feature class.  See [**this page**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-hyperlinks.htm) on using hyperlinks.

As for multiple hyperlinks, while it is definitely possible for FME to create two URLs in a single field, they won't work in ArcGIS. Your best option is to create multiple attributes (hopefully no more than two). However, your ArcGIS layer can only specify one hyperlink. I suppose you could specify another hyperlink field in a different layer, but it could become confusing.

Hope this helps.